# To iterate a map on Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am trying to access a particular element from a map in Javacsript.I tried the following way:

```
for (key in ${optionLabel}){
    alert("Inside Matched profile");
    value = ${optionLabel}.get(title);
}
```

where key is the value to be searched in optionLabel Map .

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it should be

```
${optionLabel}[key].get(title);
```

instead of

```
${optionLabel}.get(title);
```

Comment: @EnKrypt ${optionLabel} i think that's JSTL. So unless he stores it in  a variable this code won't be refactorable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is another, albeit less portable, way of iterating a map.

```
Object.keys(${optionLabel}).forEach(function (key) {
  value = ${optionLabel}[key].get(title);
});
```

this is the alternative. Using `hasOwnProperty` prevents you from iterating the prototype.

```
for (key in ${optionLabel}){
  if (${optionLabel}.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    value = ${optionLabel}[key].get(title);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys` will be having browser compatibility issues i believe.